# OptaPlanner - use groupBy for avoidOvertime but only on the Resource creating the overtime

Tags: constraints, scheduling, optaplanner, timefold

I am trying to solve a Scheduling problem that involves Resources in a work order assigned to a project. When a Resource is assigned at the exact same time as another and the sum of their assigned time is more than their Daily Capacity, the second one (only the second one) should break the Overtime constraint and be penalized.

```
If ( ResourceTime1 + ResourceTime2 > DailyCapacity ) then Resource2 breaks Overtime Constraint
```

The following code I wrote penalizes all tuple elements instead. What is the right way?

```
  private Constraint useOvertimeHard(ConstraintFactory factory) {
        return factory.forEach(WorkOrderAssignment.class)
                // Make sure Resources are the same and planned at the same period
                .join(WorkOrderAssignment.class,
                        Joiners.filtering(this::comparePeriods),
                        Joiners.filtering((woa1, woa2) -> woa1.getResource().getResourceCode().equals(woa2.getResource().getResourceCode())))
                // Group by tuples and calculate their total duration 
                .groupBy((woa1, woa2) -> woa1,
                        ConstraintCollectors.sumLong((woa1, woa2) -> woa1.getPeriod().getDuration() + woa2.getPeriod().getDuration()))
                // Filter to keep only the work order that lead to Overtime
                .filter((woa1, hours) -> hours > woa1.getResource().getTotalDailyCapacity())
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                .asConstraint("UseOvertimeHard");
    }
```

Comment: Can the resources assigned to `woa1` and `woa2` different, or are they guaranteed to be the same? (i.e. does `Objects.equals(A.getResourceCode(), B.getResourceCode())` imply A and B are the same object/represent the same resource)? How are you defining "second"? Second by time (unlikely given "assigned at the exact same time as another")? Second by an particular attribute? Is there a reason why you cannot group by the resource directly (i.e. `(woa1, woa2) -> woa1.getResource()`)?

Comment: Yes, resources are guaranteed to be the same based on the resourceCode.
Second is really just because I think sequentially (which I should not). 
If there are 2 same resources assigned for exactly the same period && it creates an Overtime, I want to penalize only one of them.
Will your suggestion of grouping by the resource directly achieve that??

Answer (score 0):

I would write the constraint like this:

```java
  private Constraint useOvertimeHard(ConstraintFactory factory) {
        return factory.forEach(WorkOrderAssignment.class)
                // Make sure Resources are the same and planned at the same period
                // Group by resource and period, calculating their total duration 
                .groupBy(WorkOrderAssignment::getResource, WorkOrderAssignment::getPeriod,
                        ConstraintCollectors.sumLong((woa) -> woa.getPeriod().getDuration()))
                // Filter to keep only the resource that has Overtime
                .filter((resource, period, hours) -> hours > resource.getTotalDailyCapacity())
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                .asConstraint("UseOvertimeHard");
    }
```

This assumes `comparePeriods` check if `Period` are equal. If `comparePeriods` instead checks a single field for equality, use that field as the key instead of the period. If it does a more complex calculation, then:

```java
private Constraint useOvertimeHard(ConstraintFactory factory) {
        return factory.forEach(WorkOrderAssignment.class)
                // Make sure Resources are the same and planned at the same period
                .join(WorkOrderAssignment.class,
                        Joiners.equal(WorkOrderAssignment::getResource),
                        Joiners.filtering(this::comparePeriods))
                // Group by tuples and calculate their total duration 
                .groupBy((woa1, woa2) -> woa1.getResource(),
                        ConstraintCollectors.sumLong((woa1, woa2) -> woa1.getPeriod().getDuration() + woa2.getPeriod().getDuration()))
                // Filter to keep only the resource that has Overtime
                .filter((resource, hours) -> hours > resource.getTotalDailyCapacity())
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                .asConstraint("UseOvertimeHard");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer essentially works, but it penalizes the Resource itself. In reality, the Planning Variable here is the WorkOrderAssignment. So even though I verify that the resource created the overtime I have to penalize the WorkOrderAssignment that resource belongs to. Still racking my brain how to do that.

Comment: You might be able to do it with `indictWith` (https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/constraints-and-score/score-calculation#constraintStreamsCustomizingJustificationsAndIndictments) if WorkOrderAssignment has a @InverseRelationShadowVariable https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/using-timefold-solver/modeling-planning-problems#bidirectionalVariable